# Require password after screen saver

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, login, screensaver, group-policy

In the screen saver settings for xp/w7
Our "wait time" and "On resume, display logon screen" are greyed out.
We've been told there is no group policy to cause this. Wait time is set to 15 minutes and the box is ticked.
How can i get ungrey the fields?
Where would the group policy for this be if there was one set?

Thank you,

EDIT:
Every computer on our network has this but when I look at the group policy there is nothing set. Our network admin has also said he hasn't set or can find any policy that can cause this. can anyone suggest where else this may be set?

EDIT: [image: Screen Saver Group Policy]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the PC is part of a domain, you cannot change it; otherwise, see the instructions below.

The location of the GPO that controls this would be: Local Computer Policy\User Configuration\Administrative Templates\Control Panel\Display and more specifically; 
"Hide screen saver tab". 
Group Policy Editor is available only in Windows 7 Enterprise, Pro and Ultimate.

You can also change registry settings ... which I do not suggest if you don't have permission. You can get into trouble if they find out you're circumventing their policies.

You can find it here:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Control Panel\Desktop
```

Delete the `ScreenSaverIsSecure` value.

If the greyout comes back after making registry change, you may have to use Group Policy Editor to make a permanent change.

Open the group policy editor by running this command:

```
gpedit.msc
```

and navigate to Local Computer Policy\User Configuration\Administrative Templates\Control Panel\Personalization

double click the "Password protect the screen saver" entry
[image]

Tick the enabled radio button and hit OK. Close the editor.

[image]

Comment: Well our network admin told us there was no group policy but the fact every pc has the screen saver settings grayed out would say other wise. Does that sound right?

Comment: Depending on the org its possible such a configuration predated the admin.  run RSOP.msc on your computer and you should be able to track back the policy setting the individual item.